# Web Based Management For LXC Containers?

Tags: software-recommendation, lxc

I need a way to manage LXC containers on Ubuntu Server 12.04 - similar to what Proxmox is. Googling indicates that openstack is one option - would this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenStack can manage virtual machine instances, and LXC deployments on bare metal.

It might be overkill for your scenario though, it requires a database server, message qeueue server, and many components to be configured (nova, swift, keystone, horizon, etc.).

If you do decide to try OpenStack, I suggest you get started with the devstack scripts:

http://devstack.org/

Answer (score 1):

Simple webpanel for Ubuntu from 12.04 is http://lxc-webpanel.github.io/.

Comment: Would be better if you could provide the gist of the answer here.